# Mysql join 3 tables no rows merging

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a query to select some rows from 3 tables but I have some special needs.

So let say I have table1,table2,table3 as t1,t2,t3
t1 contains an id column, which is a foreign key in t2 and t3.

t1 content :

```
id 
1
```

t2 content :

```
id fk val1
1  1  123
2  1  234
```

t3 content :

```
id fk val2
1  1  345
2  1  456
```

The result I'm trying to output is :

```
t2.id t3.id fk val1 val2
1     NULL  1  123  NULL
2     NULL  1  234  NULL 
NULL  1     1  NULL 345
NULL  2     1  NULL 456
```

As of now, I went to this query, but my fk column is splitted in 2 columns.

```
SELECT * FROM t2 
LEFT JOIN t3 ON (FALSE) 
WHERE t2.Fk=1
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM t2 
RIGHT JOIN t3 ON (FALSE) 
WHERE t3.Fk=1
```

Any advice how ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `coalesce()`

```
SELECT t2.id, t3.id, coalesce(t2.fk,t3,fk) as fk val1, val2 FROM t2 
LEFT JOIN t3 ON (FALSE) 
WHERE t2.Fk=1
UNION ALL 
SELECT t2.id, t3.id, coalesce(t2.fk,t3,fk) as fk val1, val2 FROM t2 
RIGHT JOIN t3 ON (FALSE) 
WHERE t3.Fk=1
```